# Link div and textbox value on div selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to sync div with textbox.

For example, I created 2 nodes i.e Node 1 and Node 2 and when I select node1 and I enter title and location then title and location should sync with Node1 so when I enter title while I have selected node1 then title value should get reflected for node1 and after entering title and location next time when I select node1 then title and location value should be reflected in my textbox.

[image]

I created this below Fiddle to demonstrate the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/quk6wtLx/2/

```
$scope.add = function (data) {
                var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
                var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
                data.nodes.push({ name: newName, nodes: [],selected : false });
            };
            $scope.tree = [{ name: "Node", nodes: [], selected: false }];

            $scope.setActive = function (data) {
                clearDivSelection($scope.tree);
                console.log(data);
                data.selected = true;
            };
```

I am not getting how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the form elements with the data you are appending to the tree.
Check this snippet

```js
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("TreeController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.delete = function (data) {
                data.nodes = [];
            };
            $scope.add = function (data) {
                var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
                var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
                data.nodes.push({ name: newName, nodes: [],selected : false, myObj: { name: newName} });
            };
            $scope.tree = [{ name: "Node", nodes: [], selected: false }];

            $scope.setActive = function ($event, data) {
             $event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.selectedData = data;
                clearDivSelection($scope.tree);
                data.selected = true;
            };

            function clearDivSelection(items) {
                items.forEach(function (item) {
                    item.selected = false;
                    if (item.nodes) {
                        clearDivSelection(item.nodes);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: circle;
}
li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 .active { background-color: #ccffcc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TreeController">
        <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
            <div ng-class="{'active': data.selected}" > {{data.myObj.name}}</div>
            <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
            <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" ng-click="setActive($event, data)"></li>
            </ul>
        </script>
        <div style="margin-left:100px;">
           Title :  <input type="text" ng-model="selectedData.myObj.name" />
           Location :  <input type="text" ng-model="selectedData.myObj.location" />

        </div>
    </ul>
```

You can check the binding documentation for AngularJs and all the possibilities https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.In your code selectedData is generated for each of the node?

Comment: Nope.
selectedData is a single variable in the scope and is assigned each time is executed the function setActive which is binded in the click event for each li element.

Comment: Is it possible to have 1 object which stores Title,Location associated with each of the node ??

Comment: Angular allows you to get a data structure in your scope and bind it to the view  only the properties you need.
You can bind both properties when executing add funcion in the push sentence in addition to current pushed object.

data.nodes.push({ name: newName, location: newLocation, nodes: [],selected : false });

Comment: I have myObj to store title and location : data.nodes.push({ name: newName,nodes: [],selected: false myObj: {}});So now what will be the change in setactive function?

Comment: You don't need to modify setActive function, you only have to bind the desired inputs with the ng-model property with the data stored in the scope selectedData.myObj.name instead of selectedData.name

Comment: Like the way you showed in your second answer but why you deleted that answer?

Comment: Any reason for using stoppropogation method?

Comment: This is because the ng-click in a li child element propagates to the li parent which also have the ng-click event binding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143508/discussion-between-learning-and-joan-maria-talarn-espelta).